# Can one issue a GET to a JSON file in the server with a key?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm currently trying to do an auto-suggestion exercise where the JSON file is located on a server, and I'm not sure if I'm understanding the webdev terminology correctly.  In one of the requirements it says:

"On the keyup [since there's an input field], issue a GET to the server with the value of input key and the name of a callback function as parameters."

I've issued a GET to a json file on a server before, but I'm confused how one can issue a GET to the file on the server with a key as a parameter for a JSON file.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Web Terminology: You don't issue a GET Request for a file, you issue a GET request for a resource identified by a URL.

The HTTP request line might look like this:

```
GET /some/thing HTTP/1.0
```

Parameters can be part of the URL, for example:

```
GET /some/thing?color=red&number=3 HTTP/1.0
```

Learn everything about URLs in the RFC: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Now maybe in your first example the resource /some/thing.json points to really was a static JSON file. But for this exercise, you'll probably need a program running on the webserver, and outputting JSON.